# How do I get a word frequency list? Can't export from Word Cloud

Tags: orange

I have a list of survey responses and want to analyze the frequency of words used.

Using Orange, I've loaded the file into a Corpus, then Preprocess Text, then Word Cloud.

The Word Cloud does not show the cloud image, and I can't figure out why. Everything appears to be set up just like the Orange documentation shows online. Word Cloud does show a nice list of words and their frequencies, but I can't copy/paste that into Excel or export that list.

How can I export that list of word frequencies into a table where one column is the word, and the other column is the count? Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to export even now. Has this feature been abandoned ?

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1) Word Cloud has a silly bug that causes the visualization sometimes not displaying. Press Regenerate word cloud and the visualization will appear.

Ad 2) This is currently not possible in Orange, but it's surprising how we haven't thought about it yet. We will make necessary modifications and the export should be available in the next release.